# Different subtitle size on Chromecast

Tags: android, casting, chromecast, google-cast, subtitle

I have a an Android application which can play movies via Googlecast. Some of these movies contain subtitles. In these cases I create a `List` of `MediaTrack` and subtitles are shown. It works fine.

In my application, there is a settings for set the size of subtitles. For setting of size I am using method `setFontScale` of class `TextTrackStyle`. This works fine as well.

But there is a problem with default size of subtitles. I prefer size `1.5f` as a default size of subtitles, so every time when playing is started I set this size as default.

I found out that there is a very different behavior for me: for some movies this size (`1.5f`) is larger. It means that for different movies I have set the same size, but in television the real sizes of subtitles are little bit different.

Does anybody know what causes this "weird" behavior? Why subtitles have different real size, when I have set the same size in my code? The subtitles are in `.vtt` format and there is nothing specific or weird in these subtitle files.